# Developing and running iOS Cordova on Windows computers?

Tags: ios, xcode, windows, cordova

I need to develop an `iOS` application based on `Apache Cordova` on my `Windows` computer.

According to this website, I need to install `Xcode` that is an `xip` file. Is it possible to install this file on Windows computer ?

Is it **practical** ? And if so, what are the **requirements** ?

Comment: you can't install Xcode in Window OS

Answer (score 2):

No you can't develp ios application with another systme than MacOS.

You should buy a Mac or try to emulate it (It seems to me that it is illegal to emulate an apple system on a host that is not an apple so I won't give any details).

Another solution is the build service of phonegap (https://build.phonegap.com). But you also need a MacOS for submit you'r apps on app store so... Welcome in the beautifull world of "Apple"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run directly install a mac file on a windows OS !
The only way to achieve this is to run a Mac Virtual Machine on your machine (I don't know where you can download a Mac image...)

Also you can try [that](https://www.macincloud.com/)